# Extract information from win_feature_info module

Tags: ansible

Trying to figure out how to display the return values of module `win_feature_info`. The keys have different depths and when registering the variable `feature_info` and doing

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |
      "Feature Install state is: {{ feature_info }}"
```

it displays all infos regarding the specific Windows feature which is:

```json
{
   "changed":false,
   "exists":true,
   "features":[
      {
         "feature_type":"Feature",
         "best_practices_model_id":"",
         "system_service":[
            
         ],
         "name":"Telnet-Client",
         "parent":"None",
         "post_configuration_needed":false,
         "display_name":"Telnet Client",
         "event_query":"",
         "description":"Telnet Client uses the Telnet protocol to connect to a remote Telnet server and run applications on that server.",
         "server_component_descriptor":{
            "CimClass":{
               "CimSuperClassName":"MSFT_ServerManagerServerComponentDescriptor",
               "CimSuperClass":{
                  "CimSuperClassName":"None",
                  "CimSuperClass":"None",
                  "CimClassProperties":[
                     
                  ],
                  "CimClassQualifiers":[
                     {
                        "Name":"dynamic",
                        "Value":true,
                        "CimType":1,
                        "Flags":"EnableOverride, ToSubclass"
                     },
                     {
                        "Name":"locale",
                        "Value":1033,
                        "CimType":7,
                        "Flags":"EnableOverride, Restricted"
                     },
                     {
                        "Name":"provider",
                        "Value":"deploymentprovider",
                        "CimType":14,
                        "Flags":"EnableOverride, ToSubclass"
                     }
                  ],
                  "CimClassMethods":[
                     
                  ],
                  "CimSystemProperties":{
                     "Namespace":"ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/ServerManager",
                     "ServerName":"ANSIBLE",
                     "ClassName":"MSFT_ServerManagerServerComponentDescriptor",
                     "Path":"None"
                  }
               },
               "CimClassProperties":[
                  
               ],
               "CimClassQualifiers":[
                  {
                     "Name":"dynamic",
                     "Value":true,
                     "CimType":1,
                     "Flags":"EnableOverride, ToSubclass"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"provider",
                     "Value":"deploymentprovider",
                     "CimType":14,
                     "Flags":"EnableOverride, ToSubclass"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"ClassVersion",
                     "Value":"10.0.0",
                     "CimType":14,
                     "Flags":"EnableOverride, ToSubclass"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"DisplayName",
                     "Value":"Telnet-Client",
                     "CimType":14,
                     "Flags":"EnableOverride, ToSubclass, Translatable"
                  }
               ],
               "CimClassMethods":[
                  
               ],
               "CimSystemProperties":{
                  "Namespace":"ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/ServerManager",
                  "ServerName":"ANSIBLE",
                  "ClassName":"ServerComponent_Telnet_Client",
                  "Path":"None"
               }
            },
            "CimInstanceProperties":[
               
            ],
            "CimSystemProperties":{
               "Namespace":"ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/ServerManager",
               "ServerName":"ANSIBLE",
               "ClassName":"ServerComponent_Telnet_Client",
               "Path":"None"
            },
            "PSComputerName":"None"
         },
         "depth":1,
         "path":"Telnet Client",
         "installed":false,
         "additional_info":{
            "MajorVersion":10,
            "MinorVersion":0,
            "NumericId":44,
            "InstallName":[
               "TelnetClient"
            ]
         },
         "depends_on":[
            
         ],
         "sub_features":[
            
         ],
         "install_state":"Available"
      }
   ],
   "failed":false
}
```

But I only want the output of `install_state`. When using `feature_info.install_state` it tells me that the variable is undefined. When trying the return value of the module like `features.display_name`, it's the same error...

Tried with `features[display_name]` as well.

Comment: `features` is a list. So: `feature_info.features.0.install_state`

Comment: Because a list is a zero-indexed compound data type: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists